# Import nested folders into Photos via Automator

Tags: mac, finder, photos, automator, photo-stream

I have a folder that is constantly updated with new photos.These photos are sorted in (nested) folders per year and per day.

I now want to make a workflow that automatically imports those photos in these nested folders to the Photos application.

I now use the action `Import files into photos`, but the problem is that only photos in that specific folder will be moved to the Photos app and not the photos in the nested/underlying folders.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: To clarify, you want to automate dragging one folder that contains all the nested images into photos and click to skip importing duplicates? Basically a two step process is what I’m seeing.

Comment: Is the some reason you're not using a **Get Selected Finder Items**   _action_ or a **Get Specified Finder Items** _action_ and then a **Get Folder Contents** _action_ with **[√] Repeat for each subfolder found**  checked before the **Import Files into Photos** _action_?